# Define python functions at runtime

Tags: python

I want to create python functions on the go, with the following template:

```python
def x(sender,data):
  r=b''  
  r+=sender.send_type0(data[0])
  r+=sender.send_type1(data[1])
  r+=sender.send_type2(data[2])
  ...
  r+=sender.send_typen(data[n])
  return r
```

I want to create many of those functions from an array which holds type data as a 2D array.
I can generate simple functions at runtime, but there I would like to run a for-statement only at the generation, and not at every call of the function.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you give more details. What type is `sender`? How can a byte string become a function? I'm not following your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use getattr to dynamically type out the attribute...

```
def x(sender,data):
    return b"".join(
        getattr(sender, "send_type"+i)(data[i])
        for i in xrange(len(data))
    )
```

I don't think you're going to find much of a performance advantage in having the function precompiled, assuming that is even possible...

Comment: So there's no fancy solution to do what I want. I' disappointed in Python... :D

Comment: What language actually supports this out of interest? And what advantage does it have over my solution of just doing it dynamically?